# Как в cat вывести номер строки, в которой найдено совпадение?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

В общем, буду весьма благодарен, если подскажете, как вывести номер строки, в которой найдено совпадение.

Делаю:

```
cat file.txt | grep 403
```

Получаю вывод:

```
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
```

А хотелось бы примерно так:

```
28541 <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
```

cat умеет такое делать, или нет?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> cat умеет такое делать, или нет?

cat не умеет такого делать, т.к. не занимается поиском совпадений.

Всё в этом вопросе сводится к grep-у и его возможностям.
Поэтому проще будет так:

```
grep -n "string_for_searching" file.txt
```

Ну или в вашем случае:

```
grep -n 403 file.txt
```

Comment: cat умеет такое делать. ```cat -n file.txt```

Comment: @misdeed вы ответьте на свой вопрос `Как в cat вывести номер строки, в которой найдено совпадение?` не пользуясь программой `grep`. То что `cat` умеет нумеровать строки в своем выводе - я в курсе.

Comment: хорошо, хорошо. Я понял. Просто я устал, поэтому уже туплю немножк. Но ```cat -n file.txt | grep 404``` работает практически так же, как и ```cat file.txt | grep -n 403``` )))

Comment: @misdeed я ни в коем случае не с наездом это пишу, а правды ради. Да,  по конечному результату будет практически так же. Кстати,   `cat -n file.txt | grep 404` и `cat file.txt | grep -n 403` даст разный результат ;]

Comment: ну да, разный)) я же говорю - я устал) 403, 404 ))ыыы

Comment: @misdeed, погуглите «useless use of cat”.

Comment: @0andriy зачем? уже давно решено

Comment: @misdeed, для самообразования (чтобы не писать ответы, например, как ниже). Но если вы не хотите...

Answer (score 5):

Да, оказывается cat умеет печатать номер строки.

```
cat -n file.txt | grep 403
```

UPD: Это может делать и grep:

```
cat file.txt | grep -n 403
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за комментарий к правке. В проверке не посмотрел автора вопроса) Всё же считаю правку уместной, лирическое отступление о гугле лишнее.

Comment: ))ok, нормально

Comment: Минус за useless use of cat.

Comment: @0andriy минусуйте, я не против. Даже - за!

Answer (score 0):

sed -n '/403/=;p' file.txt

**-n**  вывести номер строки

**;** разделитель команд

**/403/**  шаблон поиска

**p**  печать самой строки

```
echo '<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>' | sed -n '/403/=;p'
1
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
```

Comment: опцию `-n` перепутали с командой `=`?